# Create a function that generates a random number using another random function as seed

Tags: algorithm, probability

You have a function f1() that generates 0 or 1 with equal probability. Write a function f200() that generates number between the range 1 to 200 (both inclusive) using f1().

Someone suggested this below approach: toss a coin and based on the result you find out if the number will be more than half or less than half. Do this recursively with each half. Choosing half is done with powers of 2.

Is the reason for choosing powers of 2 is that we can achieve all numbers?

```
import random as rd 

def prob200(half):
    if half >= 200:
        return 0    
    #f1 can be replaced by this rd.randint(0, 1)
    toss_value = f1() 
    # check if toss falls in this current half and then change the half for next recursion. 
    # we change half from 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 36, 64, 128
    result = toss_value*half + prob200(half<<1)
    if result > 200:
        return prob200(1)
    else:
        return result

for i in range(0, 10):
    print(prob200(1))
```

Comment: if you have 4 items, then you can divide, toss a coin, and choose half, and recursively do that.  But what if you have 3 items?  How do you toss a coin and choose 1 out of 3 items with evenly distributed probability?

Comment: to tell that the random numbers are evenly distributed, you really need to count the number of times of occurrences after running it a million time and see.  For example, by using a dictionary `hash` and do something like `hash[num] = hash.get(num, 0) + 1` to "tally up" the number of times a random number occurred (`num` is the random number generated). So I  used your code (as of Jan 6, 2016), and ran it 10 millions times, and the number `200` happened `50528` times. The number`0` only occurred `40055` times. The number `1` only occurred `40726` times.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 If you have just 3 items then also the accepted answer will work.Just read through it and it will be apparent to you.

Comment: The answer you chose gives uniform distribution, however there is a problem. Since you ignore/skip random values above 200, and re-run the function if you encounter such number, you create a situation where the maximum running time is unbounded (since theoretically you can get a very long sequence of numbers above 200). The average running time is still O(N) but maximum is not.

Comment: @gen-y-s agreed. Maximum running time is unbounded. However is there any other algorithm you have in mind?

Comment: Of course. QED !!!  seriously, you create a number x with n bits (e.g. n=32 or higher if better precision is required =more uniform distribution) using the random bit generator, which you convert to your desired range r (e.g r=200) as follow: result=floor(x / 2^n * r)+1.

Comment: @gen-y-s : I guess you don't want that `+1` at last in your formula and this approach can fail(in some cases) to generate a uniform distribution if `x / 2^n` is a repeating decimal.

Comment: @gen-y-s : I just realized that maybe you are going off-topic. Can you move this discussion to chat ?

Comment: pouigt see my answer with explanation below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Very short Answer

Power of 2 is chosen for uniform distribution of random numbers generated.

### Longer Answer

Lets first make it clear that it doesn't matters if a number is power of 2 or not. We can always "achieve all numbers".

Every time you have 2 halfs of a number, you have same probability of choosing either half(Because *f1() generates 0 or 1 with equal probability*). This clearly means that there won't be any case when we will choose only 1 half out of 2, therefore **we can always achieve all numbers**.

Now the question is **Why the heck then I should choose the power of 2?**
I would answer that by saying that *if you don't choose power of 2, then you will get random numbers but with unequal probability*.

A short example of that case should make it clear, here I go :
Lets suppose you have to generate numbers in the range of 1 to 3. Now when you half it, you will either slice it into 1 2 | 3 or 1 | 2 3. Lets say you did it like 1 | 2 3.
So the probability of choosing 1 will become 1/2 = 0.5 and probability of choosing 2 or 3 will become 1/2 * 1/2 = 0.25

The root of the problem here is that when there is a range of size not equal to power of 2, and you divide that range (1 to 3 into 1 | 2 3) into 2 groups. You get 2 groups of unequal size ( group 1 has size 1 and group 2 has size 2 in above case). This variation in size of groups will lead to variation in probability of selection of the numbers in these groups.

But in case of the numbers with power of 2, it is guaranteed that you will always get groups of equal size. So, it will always give you the random number with equal probability.

Q.E.D.

Comment: So how do suggest writing f200() ? Are you saying we should use the 0/1 generator to generate an 8  bit number (256 numbers) ? But what if the number chosen is above 200 - do we re-execute the function ? because that could create problems of long or infinite wait time

Comment: @gen-y-s : Yes, it will work. Although there is an infinitesimally small probability that loop can run forever but I would still prefer it.

Comment: The point is that it cannot provide any guaranteed limit on execution time. This is usually being frown upon, epsecially that there exists a better solution... see below

Comment: I don't know why would someone down vote this answer.

Comment: @gen-y-s : The OP is not asking for the best solution of this problem. It is rather asking **Is the reason for choosing powers of 2 is that we can achieve all numbers?**, and that is answered here. It doesn't matters if it is the world's best solution or not. This is exactly why I said **you are going off-topic**.

Comment: @nomanpouigt  this was probably voted down because the runtime is not bounded theoretically, which is a serious flaw.

Answer (score 2):

You create a number x with n bits (e.g. n=32 or higher if better precision is required =more uniform distribution) using the random bit generator, which you convert to your desired range r (e.g r=200) as follow: result=floor(x / 2^n * r)+1

For example, if you use n=8, you would generate an 8-bit number using the random bit generator (the function f1) which is in the range 0-255 inclusive. Then you will divide it by 2^8=256, so we'll have a number between 0 and 255/256.  Then we multiply by 200, so we'll have result between 0 and 199.2.  Finally, we round it down and add 1 to get a number between 1 and 200.

But since we only used 8 randoms bits (n=8), the unifrmity is not that good. We effectively generated a number from 0-255 (source range) and converted it to a number from 1-200 (target range). Most numbers in the target range have one corresponding number in the source range, but others (such as the number 1) have two corresponding source numbers (0 and 1). So some numbers have 1/256 probability of occuring, while others have 2/256 probability.

To improve this we can use n=16, and then difference in probability is at most 1/2^16.

Here's a program that first tries to generate the random number using 8 bits, but if it overflows 4 times, it then uses the method I described by generating a 32-bit number and converting it to the output range:

```
import math
import random

def f1():
  return random.randint(0,1)

def rand_by_bits(n):
  v=0
  for i in range(n):
    v=(v<<1)+f1()
  return v

def rand_by_range(r):
  n=0
  t=r
  while t>0:
    t>>=1
    n+=1

  for i in range(4):
    v=rand_by_bits(n)
    if v<r:
      break

  if v>=r:
    n=32
    v=math.floor(float(rand_by_bits(n))/(1<<n)*r)

  return v+1

def main():
  random.seed()
  print(rand_by_range(200))
```

Comment: F1 doesn't return any other number other than 0 or 1.  So this won't work.

Comment: Understood but even after using this, probability of occurrence of each number is not *exactly* same even for 16 bits. Accepted answer has that advantage.

Comment: right, but any real fraction expressed as a binary value is also not completely accurate. That is "double d=1/200" also doesnt give you exactly   1/200 ,  but the closest approximation using the available precision (64 bits in this case).  The same thing for random number generators that generate values in a specified range such as between 0-1.  The distribution is uniform up to 1/2^64  , that is p(a)-p(b)<=1/2^64.

Comment: I am sorry if the question was not clear but i assume i said that the f1 just returns either 0 or 1 with equal probability. In my python implementation also the function doesn't return value between 0 and 1 but rather 0 or 1. However there are more than one number that will map to 1 if we use number of bits as 16. floor((120/2^16)*200) + 1 will also lead to 1. The more you use the number of bits there is more numbers that will map to same number.

Comment: @gen-y-s : As of **"Hope that's clear, if not you might want to drink some coffeee...."**, try to be polite here, everyone was a novice before becoming a master. And read the question clearly, this is not what was asked in first place.

Comment: @xordus look, the question here is how to create a random integer in a specified range using random bit generator (f1). Your (very trivial) answer does that, but sacrifices any guarantee on execution time, because it has a loop that depends on random generator for its exit condition (result is in the required range).  I provided a different answer where you use f1 a fixed number of times (e.g. 64 times) to generate a 64-bit number and then convert it to the required output range. This runs in constant time, the only downside is that distribution uniformity may vary by 1/2^64.

Comment: @gen-y-s: did you even read my answer ? And did you even read the question ?. Which part of this question says that it wants the best solution to do that ? Please mention it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would do it.
Given f(0,1) you are able to generate random number f(0, 2^x - 1) for any x.
For n =200 generate a function f(0, 255).
Then r = f(0,255), if r < 200 return r.
Otherwise, rerun the algo, e.g. regenerate r until r would be less than 200.